# gnuplot epslatex set table without math style enumeration

Tags: gnuplot

I encountered a problem with `GNUplot`'s `set table {output}` command, when I was working with `epslatex` terminal.

Output file was saved in a `LaTeX` like style (example):

```
    ...
    $0$ $1$ $1.1$
    $0$ $2$ $1.2$
    $0$ $3$ $1.3$
```

Can I, in an easy way, save file without `LaTeX` `$` markings using `set table` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intended. The documentation to `set table` says:

> The data format is determined by the format of the axis tickmarks (see set format), and the columns are separated by single spaces.

To fix that, you have different options:

1. Use `with table` when plotting the table data (available since version 5.0):

   ```
   set table 'output.dat'
   plot 'input.dat' with table
   unset table
   ```

   Note, that this works only with data files, but not with functions. In the latter case you would need to use `'+'` to get it right.
2. Move the `set terminal epslatex` part behind the `set table ... unset table` stuff.
3. Temporarily use a different terminal:

   ```
   set terminal epslatex # ... your stuff
   # ... a lot of code and commands

   set terminal push
   set terminal unknown
   set table 'output.tmp'
   plot x
   unset table
   set terminal pop

   # continue with your script
   ```

   This temporarily saves your current terminal `epslatex` on a stack, uses the `unknown` terminal for the table output, and then restores your original terminal.

Comment: Nice, I didn't now that I can pop/push terminals in a stack. Probably I have to modify my script -- I wrote some script which display in a latex style default gnuplot script for an example:
`gnuplot plot.plt` produce (default) in `wxt` terminal
`plotex plot.plt` (my script) produce this same script in a `LaTeX` style

Comment: I just found in the documentation, that this behavior is documented as such. And I also found a proper solution using `plot ... with table`.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work, because I `splot`. It throw an error that `w table` works only for `p`. Solution with poping/pushing terminals is quite good :) I wish that there is some global option like `unset table latexmode`.